# Complexity of a particular divide and conquer algorithm

Tags: algorithm, math, complexity-theory, big-o, divide-and-conquer

An algorithm decomposes (divides) a problem of size n into b sub-problems each of size n/b where b is an integer. The cost of decomposition is n, and C(1)=1. Show, using repeated substitution, that for all values of 2≥b, the complexity of the algorithm is O(n lg n).

This is what I use for my initial equation C(n) = C(n/b) + n
and after k-steps of substituting I get C(n) = C(n/b^k) + n [summation(from i=0 to k-1) of (1/b)^i]

k = log(base b) n

I'm not sure I'm getting all of this right because when I finish doing this i don't get n lgn, anybody can help me figure out what to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your recurrence is wrong.  Since there are b separate subproblems of size n/b, there should be a coefficient of b in front of the C(n / b) term.  The recurrence should be

> C(1) = 1
>
> C(n) = b C(n/b) +O(n).

Using the Master Theorem, this solves to O(n log n).  Another way to see this is that after expanding the recurrence k times, we get

> C(n) = b<sup>k</sup> C(n / b<sup>k</sup>) + kn

This terminates when k = log<sub>b</sub> n.  Plugging in that value of k and simplifying yields a value that is O(n log n).

Hope this helps!

Comment: wouldn't the recurrence be b^k C(n / b^k) + b^k *(n + n/b + ... + n/b^k)

Comment: or rather something like this i mean C(n) =  b^k * C(n / b^k) + k*n